# Make the drop-down menu multi-level

Tags: html, css

I have a drop-down menu as it has been shown [here](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-dropdown):

```css
.dropdown
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown button > a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e9e9ed;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="dropdown"><BUTTON>Menu</BUTTON><DIV class="dropdown-content">
    <A href="/1.php">Option 1</A>
    <A href="/2.php">Option 2</A>
    <A href="/3.php">Option 3</A>
    <DIV class="dropdown"><BUTTON><A href="/4.php">Option 4</A></BUTTON><DIV class="dropdown-content">
        <A href="/4-1.php">Option 4-1</A>
        <A href="/4-2.php">Option 4-2</A>
        <A href="/4-3.php">Option 4-3</A>
    </DIV></DIV>
</DIV></DIV>
```

But the second level of menu doesn't work (press "Run code snippet" to see). I need it to show to the right of the first level, and the width of each level must be elastic (automatically increase and reduce by content). Also the width of the root button must not be bound to the width of the first level. Ideally there should be universal style for any level, but it is not critical since I don't have tens of levels. Is there a solution without the rewriting of all the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Remove `overflow: auto;` from `.dropdown-content` so overflowing sublevels will be visible. Add `>` selector on `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` line so direct child will be displayed on hover. And the last thing is to add sublevel styling to display it on right top `.dropdown-content .dropdown-content { left: 100%; top: 0; }`

```css
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.dropdown
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content
{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e9e9ed;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}

/* To display second level on right*/
.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/1.php">Option 1 Longer</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="menu">
            <a href="/4.php">Option</a>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/4-1.php">Option 4-1</a>
            <a href="/4-2.php">Option 4-2</a>
            <a href="/4-3.php">Option 4-3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Removed some menu items for better view in "Run code snippet"

Comment: Thanks, it almost works! But how to make the width of the second level also auto-fitting?

Comment: @NickolasEtyuhibosecyu  Just add  `white-space: nowrap;` to your  `.dropdown-content`, updated my answer, happy coding! =)

Comment: How to make the not-leaf branch not a button, but a regular element of the list? I have removed the BUTTON tag, but if the text of the non-leaf is not longer than any leaf at that level, there is a background to the left and right like in all the body of the page. How to make the width of the non-leaf branch same as at the leaves?

Comment: @NickolasEtyuhibosecyu Hmm, I replaced button with `<div class="menu">` (updated my answer) and it works fine. Not sure about which background to the left and right you are talking about. Can you send me a screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: [1](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/atnqIK2Fc0PGQQ), [2](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/qb_IeSE0sC8WwQ)

Comment: @NickolasEtyuhibosecyu I see... try to add `width: 100%;` to `dropdown` (updated my answer)

Comment: I have added this to css:
`.dropdown-content div.dropdown
{
 display: block;
}`
- and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for bad knowledge of stackoverflow markup language.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function showNestedDropdown() {
          var firstDropdown = document.getElementById("firstDropdown");
          var nestedDropdownContainer = document.getElementById("nestedDropdownContainer");
      
          if (firstDropdown.value !== "") {
            nestedDropdownContainer.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            nestedDropdownContainer.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
```

```html
    <select id="firstDropdown" onchange="showNestedDropdown()">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
      
      <div id="nestedDropdownContainer" style="display: none;">
        <select id="nestedDropdown">
          <option value="">Select a nested option</option>
          <option value="nested1">Nested Option 1</option>
          <option value="nested2">Nested Option 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: This shows all options in one list, whereas I need multi-level.

Comment: Edited my answer for your need, using javascript and HTML.

Comment: No, Javascript must not be used for just the visualization of the content. If the user turns off Javascript, all the page will be broken.